# join same type table data in a table in sql

Tags: mysql

In the past I entried my data month wise due to lack of my knowledge in the month name table. But now I easily filter them, in my database, there are 6 months (Oct - Feb) table are there with same row name month-wise data can I put all the data in a table, for manually put them in a file little bit difficult for me because of id, 
so Please suggest to me to make it easily
for example, the October 2018 table is this

```
id  user_name    date      nota       veet       tree       location
1    milon   10/10/2018     43         12         111        bandel
2    kadir   11/10/2018     12         34          76        katwa
3    javed   22/10/2018     33         56          92        sirampur
4    milon   29/10/2018     55         21          78        salar
```

november 2018 table is

```
id  user_name    date      nota       veet        tree       location
1    milon   10/11/2018     13         12          71        Rampurhat
2    kadir   11/11/2018     12         24          76        katwa
3    javed   12/11/2018     53         30          62        kandi
4    milon   24/11/2018     55         27          58        salar
```

now I want SQL table like this

```
id  user_name    date      nota       veet       tree       location
1    milon   10/10/2018     43         12         111        bandel
2    kadir   11/10/2018     12         34          76        katwa
3    javed   22/10/2018     33         56          92        sirampur
4    milon   29/10/2018     55         21          78        salar
5    milon   10/11/2018     13         12          71        Rampurhat
6    kadir   11/11/2018     12         24          76        katwa
7    javed   12/11/2018     53         30          62        kandi
8    milon   24/11/2018     55         27          58        salar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new table (for example `user_locations`). Then you can copy data from first table and then copy data from second table. If you have ID column with auto-increment, and if you do not specify the ID column in select, than the ID will be assigned automatically and there will not be collision of IDs. Example of SQL for selecting from one table and inserting to another table:

```
INSERT INTO user_locations (user_name, date, nota, veet, tree, location)
SELECT user_name, date, nota, veet, tree, location FROM user_locations_november_2018
```

... however I am not sure that I understand you correctly. What exactly are you trying to do? Move data from all tables to one table (this is the one I answer). Or just select data from all the tables (in which case the UNION from other answer is correct). Or to select all data and put them into a text file?

Answer (score 0):

select * from table1 Union Select * from Table2

use The SQL UNION Operator